# Contractor IR35 Avoidance

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, contractor

I worked as a contractor in the UK public sector until September 2017.

I didn't see IR35 coming and when it came into effect my financial position was decimated.

My plan is to go back into contracting soon and I'm looking for advice on how I might protect myself from IR35, if possible.

I think I recall someone telling me Guernsey is a tax haven. Is is possible to use such havens to protect my earnings by registering a Limited Liability Company in Guernsey, for example, and working in the UK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into setting up a limited company in the UK and getting an IR35-compliant contract to use with your private sector clients. There are companies in the UK who can work with you on that for a reasonable fee, for example [Bauer & Cottrell](http://www.bauerandcottrell.co.uk/).

This is basically a contract between your limited company and the client, rather than between you as an individual and the client. Your company is contracted to provide a resource (usually you, but not necessarily) to the client, which means that you are then not considered a "disguised employee" of the company (which is what IR35 was designed to catch).

Comment: Might not help with public sector contractors I was surprised that you where able to get away with it as  HMRC  has been very tough on it contractors for decades